# When to use Valuechanged<> versus Valuesetter<> in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I've been following some of the beginner flutter tutorials on their website and was doing [this](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/interactive) tutorial for basic interactivity, specifically the part where a parent widget is used to manage the state of a child widget. There is a `ParentWidget` and `_ParentWidgetState` class the code for which is as follows:

```
class ParentWidget extends StatefulWidget {
   @override
   _ParentWidgetState createState() => _ParentWidgetState();
}

class _ParentWidgetState extends State<ParentWidget> {
  bool _active = false;

  void _handleTapboxChanged(bool newValue) {
    setState(() {
       _active = newValue;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: TapboxB(
        active: _active,
        onChanged: _handleTapboxChanged,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

`TapboxB` is a class which is a child of `ParentWidget`, the code for which is as follows:

```
class TapboxB extends StatelessWidget {
  TapboxB({this.active: false, @required this.onChanged});

  final bool active;
  final ValueChanged<bool> onChanged;

  void _handleTap() {
    onChanged(!active);
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: _handleTap,
      child: Container(
        child: Column(
          //aligns column in the centre vertically
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text(
              //sets text depending on _active boolean
              active ? 'Active' : 'Inactive',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, color: Colors.white),
            ),
            Text(
              'Tapbox B',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0, color: Colors.white),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        width: 100.0,
        height: 100.0,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          //sets colour depending on _active boolean
          color: active ? Colors.lightGreen[700] : Colors.grey[600],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The `_handleTap` method is called when the widget is clicked, which calls the `onChanged` callback, which toggles the `active` variable. In the definition for `onChanged` the type is `ValueChanged<bool>` which is documented as a "signature for callbacks that report that an underlying value has changed." If I change this however to `ValueSetter<bool>` the app works in the exact same way and nothing seems to change. So my question is what is the difference between the two of these? Is one better in this particular scenario?

Comment: Why would you change it, instead of using the documented signature? If you have no known reason to do something, don't do it, I would say.

Comment: @underscore_d granted, but this isn't exactly a project in itself, just me getting used to flutter, and so was curious

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I searched the documentation, using *flutter ValueChanged ValueSetter*, and found [this](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/ValueSetter.html):

> `void ValueSetter (T Value)`
>
> Signature for callbacks that report that a value has been set.
>
> This is the same signature as ValueChanged, but is used when the callback is called even if the underlying value has not changed. For example, service extensions use this callback because they call the callback whenever the extension is called with a value, regardless of whether the given value is new or not.
>
> `typedef ValueSetter<T> = void Function(T value);`

So they're just typedefs to the same underlying type, but one has a different semantic meaning, presumably used as self-documenting code despite the same underlying signature.

If you don't need the latter meaning of `ValueSetter`, then use `ValueChanged`, as the API thus said.